# YoutubeAPI : search video from a specific channel.?

Tags: youtube-api

How can I make a URL to search a video from a specific Channel using json feeds.

Comment: I am making a application that retrieve videos from a URL now if user want to search the video that he has watched earlier how can I provide him such a feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ***author*** parameter, in this case i'm looking for videos from **addik2you**'s channel and the keywords *Carmina Burana*:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=addik2you&v=2&alt=jsonc&q=carmina+burana
```

Comment: "carmina+burana" is the title of the video to search? and addik2you is the channel name?. isn't it

Comment: yeah... if you're looking for a specific video in the channel, that url may work. And yeah, Carmina Burana is part of the title and addik2you is the channel name.